# Implementing a News Ticker

Tags: c++, console, stl

I implemented a console version of a news ticker and I will be glad for a code review. It takes a text from the user and displays it for a given period. How may I get it better?

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    std::string slide;

    std::cout << "please enter a message for the slide: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, slide);
    
    slide.insert(slide.begin(), 5, ' ');

    std::system("clear -x");

    for(int i = 0; i < 10'000; ++i)
    {
        std::rotate(slide.begin(), slide.begin() + 1, slide.end());
        std::cout << slide + '\r' << std::flush;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms);
    }

    std::system("clear -x");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally good.  A couple of weaknesses:

- We probably want to exit if `std::getline()` returns a failed stream.  We might want to do the same for an empty input.  Personally, I'd probably prefer to accept the message as command arguments, rather than reading standard input.
- On platforms without `clear` or where `clear` doesn't accept `-x`, we'll likely get an annoying error message on the standard error channel.  We probably want to do something about that.
- What's special about 5 spaces at the start of string?  Should that be a named constant somewhere?
- `std::rotate()` moves every element of the string.  It might be better to leave the string unmodified, but to print two substrings from it (current to end, followed by beginning to current).